# 1 обработчик событий для 2-х элементов

Tags: jquery

Как обработать одно событие (щелчок мыши), применительно к двум элементам (два изображения)
Эти варианты не работают (firebug ошибку не выдаёт):

```
$('a.nivo-prevNav', 'a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
console.log("щелчок по левой или правой стрелке");
});

$('a.nivo-prevNav a.nivo-nextNav').live('click', function(){
console.log("щелчок по левой или правой стрелке");
});
```

Comment: Ошибся, исправил на nextNav

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/][1]


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.nivo-prevNav').on('click', function(){
    console.log("щелчок по левой или правой стрелке. Да и вообще, по любому элементу с классом .nivo-prevNav");
});
```

Comment: прокомментируйте с учётом nextNav

Comment: А что комментриовать? Вы не можете в надор селекторов добавить еще один?

    $('.nivo-prevNav, .nivo-nextNav').on('click', function(){
        // ваш код
    });